# Pythonic way to consolidate partially redundant objects in a list

Tags: python

I have a class for functions with integer polynomial exponents i, j, and k, as well as a floating point coefficient c, and some extraneous input variables, e.g.

G(i,j,k,c,a,A)

I have a list of these objects, and want to combine the ones where i, j, and k are the same by adding their c's, e.g., I want to reduce

```
[G(0, 0, 1, 2.0, a, A), G(0, 1, 0, 4.0, a, A), G(0, 0, 1, 1.0, a, A)]
```

to

```
[G(0, 0, 1, 3.0, a, A), G(0, 1, 0, 4.0, a, A)]
```

Is there an accepted pythonic/efficient way to do this?  I haven't been able to find any examples of someone doing this, but it seems like something that would arise frequently.

EDIT:
Below is the actual class definition for clarity.

```
class PrimitiveGaussian:
    #Primitive Gaussian of arbitrary Cartesian exponents
    #See Helgaker p. 336 for index conventions
    def __init__(self, i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, a = 1.0, A = np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0]), coefficient = 1.0):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
        self.a = a
        self.A = A
        self.coefficient = coefficient
```

Comment: Are `i`, `j`, and `k` available as attributes? Otherwise, can you do the grouping before you generate the objects in the first place?

Comment: use `collections.defaultdict(float)` to group the parameter tuples. But your snippets aren't valid python, it's difficult to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) on a sorted version of that list and specify the first three items as the key:

```
test = [(0, 0, 1, 2.0, 'a', 'A'), (0, 1, 0, 4.0, 'a', 'A'), (0, 0, 1, 1.0, 'a', 'A')]

from functools import reduce
import itertools as it

result = [reduce(lambda x, y: (*x[:3], x[3]+y[3], *x[4:]), g)
          for k, g in it.groupby(sorted(test), key=lambda x: x[:3])]
```